# Need to cut out all characters in between 2 brackets in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in python 2.7:

```
a = 'This is some text ( - 1) - And some more text (0:0) - Some more Text'
```

I would like to use a regex to get the ' - 1' out of this string.

I've tried but can't find it, thanks for your help, I've tried:

```
re.search(r'.*?\((.*)\).*', a)
```

But that didn't work. Mind you there's a second ( ) in the string but I only need the first one.

THANK YOU!

Comment: What precisely do you want to remove from the string?  Can you include your desired output for `a` after the removal operation?

Answer (score 1):

regexes are greedy by default. Your expression gets the first `(` to the last `)`

you did that:

```
re.search(r'.*?\((.*)\).*', a)
```

instead, use

```
re.search(r'.*?\((.*?)\).*', a)
```

note the non-greedy version of the match `.*?` (I just added a question mark to your regex to make it work)

Variant: avoid closing parenthesis in your group capture

```
re.search(r'.*?\(([^)]*)\).*', a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
out = re.match('.*?\((.*?)\)', a).groups()[0]
```

if you wanted to remove from the original string,

```
a.replace(out, '')
```

Comment: (NB, also check out `re.split` if you want all the fragments)

Answer (score 0):

Below code will return all the match in string:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = 'This is some text ( - 1) - And some more text (0:0) - Some more Text'
>>> regex = re.compile(".*?\((.*?)\)")
>>> result = re.findall(regex, mystring)
>>> result
[' - 1', '0:0']
```

To get first (or whatever value you want), access it by corresponding index:

```
>>> result[0]
'-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the first match found in the string, by using the optional `count` argument.

```
>>>a = 'This is some text ( - 1) - And some more text (0:0) - Some more Text'
>>>re.sub(r'\(.+?\)','',a,count=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
tmp_1 = str.split('(', mystring  )
tmp_2 = str.split(')', tmp[1])
result = tmp[0]
```

This process is simpler, and can be generalized if the brackets are nested.